# C it skip one if everytime

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a problem with 2 `if`.
The First `If` is true because `xb == 0` but the next is false because `yb==1`. In the `else if` statement both conditions are satisfied.

```
xb = 0;
yb = 1;
xz = 0;
yz = 0;
if (xb == 0) {
    if (yb == 0) {
        ...
    }
} else if(xb == 0) {
    if (yb == 1) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Why is the `else if` skipped, when both are true?

Comment: @IrgendSonRandom please read this: [ask], and provide a [MCVE]. And format your code properly.

Comment: When I understood your question correctly: Delete your `else` in `else if` statement then the second part will run correctly. Otherwise the `else if(xb==0)` will be checked only if the first `if(xb==0)` is false.

Answer (score 0):

The third `if` is executed only if the first `if` test is false because of the `else` keyword.

Change your ifs to this:

```
xb = 0;
yb = 1;
xz = 0;
yz = 0;
if (xb == 0) {
    if (yb == 0) {
        // both xb and yb and 0 ...
    } else
    if (yb == 1) {
        // xb is 0 and yb is 1 ...
    }
} else {
    if (yb == 0) {
        // xb is not 0 and yb is 0 ...
    } else
    if (yb == 1) {
        // xb is not 0 and yb is 1 ...
    }
}
```